# Correcting Crystal Report Data Sources -- Tables not following Server

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

Been struggling with this on a few Crystal Reports, and it's super evident when testing inside of the CR editor.

My report has one database connection (OLE DB to a a SQL Server). On the vast majority of my CR's, when I hit F5, and log into the SQL server for a data preview, the rest of the report will follow whatever database I select.

On some reports, it does not--and the tables in the underlying connection are stuck to a specific database.

Is this a setting within Crystal Reports for the tables below a connection to have their own "Catalog"?

I've found I'm able to correct this somewhat by changing each of the tables Catalog's manually, but I use these CRs against multiple databases.

Has anyone encountered this, and hopefully found a way to fix it without re-creating the report from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the database. If this doesn't help try to update the connection to ODBC and back to OLDE DB.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to try would be to click on Database in the menu bar, then click "Log On or Off Server".  This will allow you to select a database server that the report is connected to and then Log Off from that connection, repeat this for all connected databases.  Then click Database on the menu bar again and then click "Set Datasource Location" to update the report with the database you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

[image: set datasource location]

This usually works for me:
right click on database fields and left click on set datasource location.
some times you will need to update every table.
but most of the time - after making the connection to database you can update all tables automatically